# Where is the Add to Cart button in journal3 theme?

Tags: php, opencart, e-commerce, opencart-3, journal

So I am using journal3 theme (opencart) and I can't seem to find where's the Add to Cart button at.

[image]

I know that Buy Now & Question buttons are at Journal > Product Extras > Product Extra Button

But where can I find the Add to Cart button and edit its content? (text, behavior, etc.)

Please any clue would matter the world to me I've been searching it for two consecutive nights.

Comment: The best way to ask Journal developers... Because this theme written not  according OpenCart standards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made a research for you.

Product page button text you will find in language file **catalog/language/en-gb/en-gb.php**, line

```
$_['button_cart']           = 'Add to Cart';
```

Icon and setting of this button you will find in

**Journal > Styles > Product Page > DEFAULT**

On this setting page find **Buttons > Add to Cart**

Answer (score -1):

I found it at Admin Panel **Design -> Language Editor**